# Add To Homescreen (ATH) javascript issue; addToHomescreen is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to use the AddToHomescreenWindow from http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen in my wordpress site, but I have no idea why it's not working..

What have I done yet:

**Loaded the script files**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'homescreen-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/js/addtohomescreen.js', array('jquery'), true );
wp_enqueue_style( 'homescreen-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/css/addtohomescreen.css' );
```

**Loaded the script inside the < head > (header.php)**

```
<script>
addToHomescreen();
</script>
```

**but I still get the error message:**

Error message in console: ReferenceError: addToHomescreen is not defined

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?